# OS X app in Xcode suddenly not replacing already running process/instance

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode5

I'm developing a background only OS X app in Xcode. I've archived the app and placed `.app` file in `/Library/Input Methods/`. It's running fine. Yesterday, every time I modified something & then run it in Xcode, newly built app would run instead of the one I placed in `/Library/Input Methods/` and I could see the Console output of the newly built app.

But suddenly today this doesn't happen. The one in `/Library/Input Methods/` runs and nothing is shown in console. Also when I run the app in Xcode, I can see two instances of the app in `Activity Monitor` (one from `/Library/Input Methods/` and other one from Xcode).

I'm using Xcode 5.1 and OS X 10.9

I tried quiting-restarting Xcode, restarting Mac, cleaning project, deleting data in `Derived Data` folder etc. But nothing worked. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to run the app from Xcode BEFORE it gets started from the system i.e. by changing input method. So the app process of Xcode build needs to be run first.